# This site is copying StackExchange questions

Tags: discussion

This site is copying StackExchange questions. It seems like a spam site. They probably have ads, but I'm using an ad blocker. I was searching for something and came across my own question.

http://www.gp958.com/questions/52482.html

Comment: Thanks for your report!  These are gathered on Stack Overflow's meta site and this site has been reported [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/193578/154510).  Feel free to post an answer directly on that question if you find any other ripoff sites that haven't been reported.

Comment: A quick note for future visitors: the meta question Mr. Read points to is no longer in use. Instead, the [new way](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers) of reporting sites that copy our content without attribution is to use the **contact us** link at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Newer, better advice can be found at: [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200177/21960)